# Synching a modifiable list over multiple views in MVVM

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm, singleton

I'm trying to learn MVVM for VB.NET and WPF. Now I've struck a situation where I can't find a way to handle it. The actual data in my program is very specific, so I'll use a similar construct here.

At first, there are departments. They do have a department manager. They are usual Models and do have a usual ViewModel.
Then, there are employees. They do have a name and an id. Employees are Models too and they do have a ViewModel.

- It is planned to have a view to edit the list of employees.
- There is a view to edit departments.

The department view has a dropdown to select the department manager from the employees.

Now my question: where and how do I manage the employees, so I can achieve that the drop down list of all departments are updated if new employees are added?

So far, I've used a singleton as `EmployeeService` that ensures 2 things:

1. 5 employees are in the default list and cannot be modified.
2. Added entries are no duplicates regarding id.

The `EmployeeService` uses an `ObservableCollection(Of Employee)` to organize the models. Furthermore it offers a `Public Property Employees As ReadOnlyObservableCollection(Of Employee)`.

The `DepartmentViewModel` has a `Public Property EmployeeOptions As String()` to populate the dropdowns. It adds an `CollectionChanged` event handler to the service's `ReadOnlyObservableCollection` (treating it as `INotifyCollectionChanged`) that refills `EmployeeOptions` and fires `OnPropertyChanged("EmployeeOptions")` afterwards.

However I feel this is not quite a good way to do this, is it?

I wonder if I should make a `EmployeeServiceViewModel` that wraps the `EmployeeService` and provides something like one `ObservableCollection(Of EmployeeViewModel)` for all `DepartmentViewModel` instances? On the one hand that means to have a singleton `EmployeeServiceViewModel`, and I always read "you shouldn't use view model singletons". On the other hand, the view to edit the employee list requires that `EmployeeServiceViewModel` anyways, right?

Has anybody a structure diagram or something where an editable list of models populates multiple view's dropdowns?

Comment: Subscribing to CollectionChanged is certainly how I've done it myself in past, I'm not sure why you have reservations about it. I guess my first question though would be why are you using two arrays? Why can't both your employee view and department view just reference the same ObservableCollection?

Comment: @Mark Currently I'm using one String array in DepartmentViewModel, and one ObservableCollection(Of Employee) in EmployeeService. I do not have a ViewModel for the employee view yet. I'm wondering if I should abandon the logic in the EmployeeService, implement it in the EmployeeServiceViewModel and utilize that viewmodel's list in my DepartmentView as you're suggesting. Sounds better than chain-updating dozens of String arrays.

Comment: I would definitely recommend that, there's no point having multiple copies of the same data that needs constant synchronization. The only downside to doing this is that you can wind up passing around a lot of pointers to various objects, but a dependency injection framework like Ninject or Unity etc will take care of all that for you and support all kinds of incredibly useful functionality (e.g. making sure that every object created in the logical tree for a given screen object all point to the same service). And of course you can also use it to inject Mock objects for unit testing.